# R BACE error with BMS package: leading minor is not positive definite

Tags: r, variables, average, bayesian, reduction

I am trying to perform Bayesian Averaging via `BMS` Package in R but I am constantly getting error message:

> Error in chol.default(symmat) :
>     the leading minor of order X is not positive definite

I have weekly Google Trends data set from April 2004 to May 2014, which contains 235 variables, which will be used as predictors. I would like to reduce their amount with bayesian averaging. 
Problem probably is, that my depending variable is monthly, so after the `fransformation` I am stuck with 125 observations and 235 predictors.

I am able to conduct `BACE` on maximum of 12 predictors, after this amount I get the error message mentioned above. Is there a method how can I use all 235 variables at time?

I am following [this tutorial](http://bms.zeugner.eu/tutorials/bms.pdf).

Comment: In case this is still relevant for you: The error message means that your matrix of predictors has less than full rank. In other words, some of your predictors are perfectly correlated. This is the reason why the bms algorithm fails.